# Why do I get a server 500 error with my php code

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating a program that reads from a text file and displays a random word and the words definition. whenever I run the web page with mamp, I get a server 500 error when the php is used.

here is my Javascript

```
function fetchTerm() {


   var myXMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   myXMLRequest.open("GET", "play.php", true);
   myXMLRequest.send();

}

function createRandomWordDefin() {

   var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

   document.getElementById("defin").innerHTML = json.defintion;
   document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = json.word;
}
```

here is my php

```
<?php
//task 1 open and read the file into array
$line = file("./play.txt");
//task 2 randomly select a term and definition
list($word, $name, $definition)= preg_split("/[\t]/",trim(($line[array_rand($line)]));
//tsk3 create a json object
$json =array(
    "definition"=> $definition,
    "name" => $name,
    "word" => $word
);
//task4 reeturn the json object
header("Contenttype:Application/json");
print(json_encode($json));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Array elements should separated by comma `,`, You should enable error reporting to know where is the error.

```
$json =array(
    "definition"=> $definition,
    "name" => $name,
    "word" => $wordm
);
```

Comment: This is not the issue my actual code did not have this error